# How to tell python non-class objects from class objects

Tags: python, class, attributes, types, descriptor

I am new to python. I think non-class objects do not have **bases** attribute whereas class objects do have it. But I am not sure. How does python\cpython checks if an object is non-class or class and passes the correct arguments to the object's descriptor attribute accordingly during the attribute access?

============================================

updated:

I was learning how `__getattribute__` and descriptor cooperate together to make bounded methods. I was wondering how class object & non-class object invokes the descriptor's `__get__` differently. I thought those 2 types of objects shared the same `__getattribute__` CPython function and that same function would have to know if the invoking object was a class or non-class. But I was wrong. This article explains it well:

http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods

So class object use `type.__getattribute__` whereas non-class object use `object.__getattribute__`. They are different CPython functions. And **super** has a third `__getattribute__` CPython implementation as well.

However, about the **super** one, the above article states that: 
quote and quote

---

**The object returned by super() also has a custom _*getattribute*_() method for invoking descriptors. The call super(B, obj).m() searches obj._*class*_._*mro*_ for the base class A immediately following B and then returns A._*dict*_['m']._*get*_(obj, A). If not a descriptor, m is returned unchanged. If not in the dictionary, m reverts to a search using object._*getattribute*_().**

---

The statement above didn't seem to match my experiment with Python3.1. What I saw is, which is reasonable to me:

`super(B, obj).m ---> A.__dict__['m'].__get__(obj, type(obj))`

objclass = type(obj)

`super(B, objclass).m ---> A.__dict__['m'].__get__(None, objclass)`

**A** was never passed to `__get__`

It is reasonable to me because I believe **objclass** (rather than **A**) 's mro chain is the one needed within **m** especially for the second case.

Was I doing something wrong? Or I didn't understand it correctly?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. Perhaps an example is in order?

Comment: Why do you need to care about this?

Comment: Seconded. Caring about this goes against one of the things Python was developed for.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters asked: Why do you care? Usually that's a sign of not using Python the way it was meant to be used.

A very powerful concept of Python is [duck](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) [typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). You don't care about the type or class of an object as long as it exposes the attributes you need.

Answer (score 0):

how about inspect.isclass(objectname)?

more info here: http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html